# multipart/form-data in post to api

Tags: c#, json, connection

I'm trying to send some data into the provided API. The content type of the data is `multipart/form-data; boundary=xxx`. When I'm posting through Postman everything works fine, but when I'm doing it in a C# server I get a 500 error. Below is my function:

```cs
private static async Task<string> ApiPostRequest(string authToken, string jsonRequest)
{
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", authToken);

        var content = new MultipartFormDataContent();

        var jsonPart = new StringContent(jsonRequest, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

        content.Add(jsonPart, "json_data");

        var response = await client.PostAsync(MesaApiUrlPost, content);

        if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)
        {
            throw new Exception("Error.");
        }

        return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }
}
```